# Can we apply placeholder settings for rendering variants?

Tags: sxa, placeholders

As SXA is supporting placeholder settings for different renderings, Is there any way that we can setup placeholder settings for rendering variants too for a single rendering?

Answer (score 4):

welcome to SSE.

The short answer is, yes you can. Here is the reference material: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/add_a_dynamic_placeholder_to_a_rendering_variant

The longer answer:

- Add a placeholder to your rendering variant and add the `Placeholder Key` value. Make sure you do not add a dash to the key name
- Go to your placeholder settings for your site `<siteroot>/Presentation/Placeholder Settings` and add a placeholder
- In the `Data` section enter the `Placeholder Key` you just added into your rendering variant and suffix it with `*` to make it dynamic. So if your key was `MyRenderingVariantPlaceholder`, you would enter `MyRenderingVariantPlaceholder*`

Now you can restrict the use of renderings by using the allows controls field like you would in other Placeholder Settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Richard. But what if we have already created a placeholder in Partial design and need to restrict a particular rendering variant of a component in that placeholder. Thanks