# Can Rendering variants be restricted on placeholder settings?

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8.

You can only specify Allowed components not Rendering variants in Placeholder settings.

Is there possibility to limit which Rendering variants of certain component can be used in placeholder settings?

I have already found similar question here [Can we apply placeholder settings for rendering variants?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13548/can-we-apply-placeholder-settings-for-rendering-variants) but the answer is about adding placeholders into Rendering variants which isn't my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create completely new component by cloning existing one. Rendering variant from original component would be copied to cloned component as Default one.

This newly created cloned component will be then placed into list of Allowed Components for placeholder instead of original component.

This option however increases complexity of the solution and also number of components in toolbox.